# Multiple Breeze Controller with Single Entity Manager

Tags: breeze

I use Breeze for Large Business Application, I Have Single api controller

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
```

but the number of line grows up (reach 600 Lin)... brings problem on maintainability

I want to use single Entity Manager, for client side cache service. How could I manager it... help plz!

Answer (score 0):

For my largest Entity Manager I made the controller a partial class with the Metadata function and place the query methods in separate files based on their content:

**One file (called DatamartController.cs):**

```
public partial class DatamartController : ApiController
  {
    readonly EFContextProvider<DatamartContext> _contextProvider =
       new EFContextProvider<DatamartContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }
}
```

**Another file (I called this one Networking.cs for my networking tables):**

```
 public partial class DatamartController
 {
    [HttpGet]
    [BreezeQueryable]
    public IQueryable<TPv2.Models.IPAddress> IPAddresses()
    {
        IQueryable<TPv2.Models.IPAddress> list =
            _contextProvider.Context.IPAddresses.Where(p => !p.DeletedFlag);
        return list;
    }
 }
```